# OpenOffice Base 4.0.1 Printing a right aligned field

Tags: printing, openoffice-base

I have a problem with a form created with OpenOfice Base 4.0.1

In the form there are some text fields, multi-line, right-justified.

While typing everything is ok: it works all right, instead printing is not performed correctly: the fields with right alignment are cut at the end of the text (the last character of the text is truncated). 
It looks like an alignment problem, as if the system is not able to perform the correct calculation of the starting position of the text and because of this the text is slightly cut off at the end.

I've tried using various fonts and printers, but the result has not changed.

In bordered fields text goes over the line of the edge.
[image: preview example]

OpenOffice Base also does not allow you to format text indentation or margins in a text box, and then I don't know how to fix it

Comment: is not a problem of field size or width, the final character is truncated only in print (you can see only a part of the last character) even if I write a few characters, I think it is a problem of OO print system

Comment: Windows 7 and Windows XP both 32bit (Italian Language).

Comment: It's very simple to reproduce: Start new DB, Create a new Form, add a text field, open properties and set Multi Line, Right-Align, type "Hello World" as default text and save. Double click on the Form then File->"Print...", enlarges the window for a better view of the preview and if it behaves as in my case, the text goes off the right edge.

Answer (score 1):

Try Menu `File` -> `Export as PDF` instead of printing the form directly. When printing directly, OpenOffice Base seems to have issues with the field's border. When exporting to PDF instead, OpenOffice keeps the field's content distant from the field's border:

[image: Base Form exported as PDF]